# Form Key Problems After Changing Domains 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, session, form-key

After changing domains, from `dev.mysite.com` to `mysite.com` I can no longer login to the backend, I am getting below error:

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Also, Customers cannot sign in and products cannot be added to bags.

These are all issues with the form_key, but I have no idea where to even start looking for answers, **the system.log only shows:**

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php on line 93

[This Post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7478/invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page-error-on-product-save) suggested to double check cookie_domain, and to increase max_input_vars in php.ini but neither of these had any affect. I have also tried using a fresh .htaccess file

Additional info: I have two sites on this Magento installation (everything worked fine before domain change) and the domains simply changed like so:

```
dev.site1.com -> site1.com

dev.site2.com -> site2.com
```

And yes I refreshed cache and session data and restarted apache and mysql after every single change.

Comment: can you try re-indexes or url rewrite?

Comment: @Ajaypatel Can you be specific? What file am I editing?

Answer (score 1):

The method that solved my problem included two main things:

I had to fix my cookie domain

http://site1.com -> .site1.com

http://site2.com -> .site2.com

Step #2 was the weirdest

I had to go to my old login panel:

http://dev.site1.com

(yes the dns for the subdomain still pointed to the same ip)

and then I was able to login just fine and it actually redirected me correctly to

http://site1.com/index.php/admin/

I will continue to look into why I needed to do this

Comment: don't forget to clear your browser's cookies and cache. If you use FQDN with an SSL, add `www` before your cookie domain. This also comes in handy when setting up a staging area with another subdomain (e.g. `staging`)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [number of different issues](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/05/fixing-magento-login-problem-after-a-fresh-installation/) that cause the errorless admin login behavior you're seeing, but they all go back to Magento not being able to set or read the session cookie.  Magento uses sessions to pass error messages between pages — that's why you don't see an error message.  Magento also uses sessions to store the "is logged in" value, so not setting sessions also causes the core error behavior.

Possible causes include

- Local computer time vs. server time mismatch, causing instant cookie invalidation.  Make sure your server time is correct.
- Incorrect permissions on `var/session`, preventing session files from being saved
- Incorrect configuration of database/redis/other session storage, preventing saving of session values
- A module is [instantiating sessions to early](http://alanstorm.com/magento_sessions_early), preventing the correct session names from being set
- You're a developer using multiple URLs and have [multiple cookie domains](http://blog.philwinkle.com/i-cant-login-to-magento-admin/)
- Another developer has somehow modified `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php`, creating a hard to track down bug
- The cookie domain in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management` doesn't match the actual site domain.
- You're using the `localhost` as your server domain, and using a version of webkit that has trouble/bugs setting cookies for `localhost` in some situations.

The short term fix is to just delete your cookie for the domain. That's often enough to solve the problem.  If it persists, figure out which of the above reasons is the reason for your error, and take steps to address it (fix permissions, etc.)

=================================================================

Enable debugging in your site to see error

1.Open your Magento installation directory. Locate and open index.php file.
And find

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Replace above code form below code:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

6.Save this file and upload to the server. Reload your website page to see errors.

[For more detail see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel?rq=1)

Comment: I don't see /*error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);*/ in my index.php but I did uncomment the # sign from ini_set('display_errors', 1); and add $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true; and nothing changed, nothing new in system log either. Just says "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Comment: I have updated the code plz check

Comment: How do I "just delete your cookie for the domain" ? none of the other issues solved the problem

Comment: Have you check permissions on var/session ??

Comment: yes they are all completely open (777)

Comment: I looked into all of the issues stated, the only one that I had to change was the "multiple cookie domains" issue, which i swore was going to fix the issue, but nothing happened

Comment: Please see here may be it will help you http://www.webcroppers.com/magento-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page/

Comment: as i stated in the question, increasing max_input_vars had no affect